# Execute ajax requests with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to execute 3 ajax requests using jquery when my html page loads. I've tried queues, set async to "false" and everything imaginable.

I'm sending requests to a webservice that then queries a database and then the webservice returns the results in json.

The problem is that when I access the page, he executes one requests, or two or all of them. Everytime I refresh the page the results are different.

Here is my code:

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $.ajax({

        url : "/api/apiJ.php?request=getProfileInfo&id=" + $.cookie("id") + "&token=" + $.cookie("token"),
        type : "GET",
        success : function(data) {

            console.log("Dados: " + data);

            var profile = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            if (profile.resp == "true") {

                $("#username").html(profile.Nome);

                $("#avatar").html('<img src="' + profile.Avatar + '" alt=""/>');

                $("#nome").html(profile.Nome);
                $("#email").html(profile.Email);
                $("#local").html(profile.Cidade + ", " + profile.Pais);

                $.cookie("token", profile.token);

                $(document).dequeue();

            }
        }
    });

    $.ajax({

        url : "/api/apiJ.php?request=getMyContacts&id=" + $.cookie("id") + "&token=" + $.cookie("token"),
        type : "GET",
        success : function(data) {

            var cont = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            console.log("Contatos: " + data);

            if (cont.resp == "true") {
                var htmls = '<ul>';

                for (var i = 0; cont[i] != null; i++) {
                    //htmls += '<li class="thumbnail" >';
                    htmls += '<li class="thumbnail" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: ' + (6 + 128 * i) + 'px; display: list-item;">';

                    if (cont[i].Colega.Avatar == "")
                        htmls += '<a title="' + cont[i].Colega.PrimeiroNome + ' ' + cont[i].Colega.UltimoNome + '" href="gallery/blank-profile.jpg" rel="gallery" class="cboxElement"> <img src="gallery/blank-profile.jpg" alt="" /></a>';
                    else
                        htmls += '<a title="' + cont[i].Colega.PrimeiroNome + ' ' + cont[i].Colega.UltimoNome + '" href="' + cont[i].Colega.Avatar + '" rel="gallery" class="cboxElement"> <img src="' + cont[i].Colega.Avatar + '" alt="" /></a>';

                    htmls += '<p>' + '<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Apagar"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>' + '<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Editar"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>' + '<span>' + cont[i].Colega.PrimeiroNome + ' ' + cont[i].Colega.UltimoNome + '</span>' + '</p></li>';
                }

                htmls += '</ul>';

                $("#small_grid2").html(htmls);

                $.cookie("token", cont.token);

                $(document).dequeue();

            }
        }
    });

    $.ajax({

        url : "/api/apiJ.php?request=getFileListFromUser&id=" + $.cookie("id") + "&token=" + $.cookie("token"),
        type : "GET",
        success : function(data) {

            var files = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            if (files.resp == "true") {

                var htmls = '';

                for (var i = 0; files.Ficheiros[i] != null; i++) {

                    htmls += '<dt><a id=\"' + files.Ficheiros[i].idFicheiro + '\" href=\"' + files.Ficheiros[i].url + '\" style=\"color\:\#000\">' + files.Ficheiros[i].nome + '</a></dt>' + '<dd class="profile_files">' + files.Ficheiros[i].nome + ' <p align="right" >';

                    htmls += '<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Apagar"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Editar"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a></p> </dd>';

                }

                $("#listaFicheiros").html(htmls);

                $.cookie("token", files.token);

            } else {
                var htmls = '<dt><a href="#" style="color:#000">Não existem ficheiros para este utilizador</a></dt>' + '<dd class="profile_files"> 0 ficheiros encontrados </dd>';

                $("#listaFicheiros").html(htmls);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

This is driving me crazy...

Comment: Is this code hosted on a server or are you trying to call it from a local html page?

Comment: at worst u could chain the 3 request so each one is called sequentially in the success() of the previous..perhaps this behavior is happening because JS is single threaded and the response from one request arrives while the engine is processing the previous call and so it gets queued (and then somehow lost)..

Comment: ajax is asymmetrical.  You either need to chain them to make them symmetrical like @SajjanSarkar stated, or re-think your implementation.    I think you might want to re-think what you are doing and re-write it so that things do not rely on a particular order.  Chaining slows down your page.  Asymmetrical loads are faster for the end user.

Comment: @mrbinky3000 It's "asynchronous" and not "asymmetrical" ... but the rest is true :D

Comment: Or better yet, combine the three into a single request to the server, even if it means making an intermediary webservice that gets data from the three webservices and combines their results into a single response.

Comment: @Kevin B fair suggestion but that might be a huge redesign

Comment: Do your ajax requests depend on each other, meaning ajax request 2 shouldn't be sent before ajax request 1 is complete? (considering on each request you're changing the values stored in cookies.) If that's the case, your only option short of combining to one webservice is to request them sequentially rather than all at the same time. This means moving request 2 into the success of request 1, and request 3 into the success of request 2. The same could be done with deferred objects.

Comment: @Kevin B they do not depend of each order. The order isn't important.

Comment: Side note: requests don't simply get *"lost"*. If the success callback doesn't happen, the error callback will otherwise there will be an error in the console.

Comment: @KevinB What I meant was, what happens if i fire off 3 AJAX requests then response1 arrives and the JS Engine starts executing the success() handler. While this success() handler code is executing suppose the remaining 2 responses arrive, where do they go?  They get queued,i'm guessing (since JS is single-threaded).I do not know what is the maximum queue size that JS will allow. Also what happens if the 2 responses are very large(say binary image data) and the browser cache size is exceeded? My guess(and there's a question in there too) is that the JS Engine would dequeue the items till its ok

Comment: They get queued in a sense, but they can't get lost. the next scope that needs to execute simply waits it's turn until it is time to execute it. If there is a maximum and it is being reached, there's probably something wrong in the code logic creating thousands of requests. Even then, the browser limits ajax requests to the same domain to x at a time depending on browser ( some are as low as 2 ). That limit simply makes the next request wait until one of the current ones complete.

Comment: I suspect that the `error: fn` callback is being called when he doesn't get a response from a particular request with a server or network error. That is far more likely than a request somehow being lost by the javascript engine.

Comment: I tried sequentially as @Sajjan Sarkar said and it worked. It's a little bit slow but I'm having some issues with the server.

Thank you for all the help guys.